# Cordova getDirectory returns errorcode

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to access the filesystem in a cordova iOS app, but it always returns error code 3 (ABORT_ERR) when I use the `getDirectory` method.

I'm using the following code:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    console.log(fileSystem.name);
    dataDir = fileSystem.root.getDirectory("ozzie", {create: true}, getDir, fail);
}

function getDir(dir) {
    console.log("successfull got directory", dir);
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log("error", error.code);
}
```

Which returns me the `fileSystem.name` ("persistent"), but it never gets the directory. This always returns error.code = 3, which according to the phonegap documentation is ABORT_ERR.

Has anyone had this behavior before?

Comment: Hitting the same error, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is that you try to create two directories, for example: `directory1/directory2`

In iOS, you should create one first, and then the other.

In iPad, the `Documents` directory does not exist.